# How can I display the added Friends to their respective user friends list?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am developing a feature same like Facebook. means a user can send a friend request and then that specific user will accept the friend request. so it means they both become friends with each other.
Now how can I display them in such a way that user A is a friend of User B and vice versa?
That's how I have developed it but can't display both of the users in the friend's list.

models.py:

```
class AddToNetwork(models.Model):
    NETWORK_CHOICES = (
        ('ADD', 'Add'),
        ('ACCEPT', 'Accept'),
        ('DELETE', 'Delete'),
    )
    id = models.UUIDField( primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    add_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="add_to", null=True, blank=True)
    added_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="add_from", null=True, blank=True)
    network_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices = NETWORK_CHOICES)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.add_to)
```

Sending a friend request using the following method/logic:

```
def addToNetwork(request, id):
    try:
        add_to = User.objects.get(id = id)
        current_user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
        network = AddToNetwork.objects.create(add_to = add_to, added_from=current_user,network_status = 'ADD')
        messages.success(request,f'Request Sent to {add_to.first_name} {add_to.last_name}')
        return redirect('userProfileDetail', id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        add_to = None
    return render(request,'network/network_userProfile.html')
```

Accepting a friend request using the following logic:

```
def acceptNetworkRequest(request, id):
    try:
        # if 'accept_friendRequest' in request.GET:
        friend_request = AddToNetwork.objects.get(id = id)
        print("\n Friend Request \n", friend_request)
        friend_request.network_status = 'ACCEPT'
        friend_request.save()
        messages.success(request, f'You accepted {friend_request.added_from.first_name} as a friend!')
        return redirect('friends', id)

    except AddToNetwork.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request,'network/friendRequestList.html')
```

Logic to display the friends in the respective profiles:

```
def friends(request, id):


    user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
    if user:
        approved_friends = AddToNetwork.objects.filter(Q(added_from_id = user),network_status = 'ACCEPT')



    context = {
        'friends': approved_friends,
        # 'approved': friend_to,
        # ' key' : value
    }
    return render(request, 'friend_list.html', context)
```

Now I want to use the model attribute add_to and added_from so that I can display the friends in their respective profiles. At the moment, either it displays a friend which uses the `add_to` attribute or `added_from`.

template for `friends_list`:

```
            {% for friend in friends %}
              <tr>
                <!-- <td scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</td> -->
                <td>{{friend.add_to.first_name}} {{friend.add_to.last_name}}</td>
                <br>
               </tr>
             </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

is there anyone who can guide me?

EDIT:
my user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    id = models.UUIDField( primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the list of friends from your current model would be something like this:

```py
User.objects.filter(
    Q(add_from=user)& # get requests sent by the user
    Q(add_from__network_status='ACCEPT')| # must be accepted
    Q(add_to=user)&   # and those sent to the user
    Q(add_to__network_status='ACCEPT') # must be accepted
)
```

This should work fine but you might want another model that actually stores the friend lists, you may find it to be more concise and manageable. Something like storing friends as a m2m field on the user or having a `FriendList` model that stores the main user and their friends.

**Edit** - my code above is incorrect, the `add_from` field accesses the related `AddToNetwork` objects but then doesn't access the users related to those objects. It's necessary to add `__add_to` and `__added_from` respectively to get *back* to the user again.

```py
get_user_model().objects.filter(
    Q(add_from__add_to=user)& # get requests sent by the user
    Q(add_from__network_status='ACCEPT')| # must be accepted
    Q(add_to__added_from=user)&   # and those sent to the user
    Q(add_to__network_status='ACCEPT') # must be accepted
)
```

Comment: I applied the same logic but still, it shows the friends to that user who accepts the friend request.

Comment: The combination of the two Q() expressions gets both added to and added from requests, is that not what you want?

Comment: yes. it is displaying both users. If I have received the request, after accepting it, it should display the added_from users only. not add_to users.

Comment: and same goes for added_from users.

Comment: Is your issue that it includes the user themselves as part of the filter? You can do `.exclude(id=user.id)` to keep them out the queryset

Comment: and on the other side. it should display the add_to users as friends

Comment: But that wouldn't get you a complete friends list as requests can be sent by the user and received from other users and still end up with a friend connection, so you need to look at both fields

Comment: it says, ['“jack.jackson@gmail.com” is not a valid UUID.']

Comment: yeah, you are right. I mean there should be a kind of logic through which I can friends from both ends.

Comment: "jack.jackson@gmail.com" is not the user ID surely? Did you put `user.id` in the exclude?

Comment: yes, I did. now it shows the same old friend list. and it is showing the current logged in user 2 times with its real friend.

Comment: do you want me to change something from the templates? to change the results?

Comment: okay, what if I add a new model with m2m relation with AddToNetwork model to display the exact friends list?

Comment: user:13448841  so now, I am able to fix the issue to remove the currently logged-in user from the friend's list but still not able to display the remaining friends in the user's friend list. I think the issue is something in the ORM query.

Comment: Are you querying the `User` model? What isn't it returning that you are expecting it to return?

Comment: I have a relation of ForeignKey with User model and I am querying from AddToNetwork model. at the moment it displays the friend only using add_to attribute. I want to display the friends from both added_from and add_to attributes. how can I send a screenshot in the comments?

Comment: Use the `User` model as I suggested in my answer, it will be much easier that way

Comment: so do I need to add a self relation with m2m option?

Comment: No because you can access `AddToNetwork` through a reverse accessor, specifically the `add_from` and `add_to` related names that you have already declared

Comment: okay, let me try your solution. and I have also edited my question and added the user model

Comment: I've just edited my answer as it wasn't getting the status via the through relationship

Comment: Cannot query "jack.jackson@gmail.com": Must be "AddToNetwork" instance.

Comment: saying, it should be AddToNetwork Insatnce. not thw User instance

Comment: and what are you referring to the user in your solution? the currently logged-in user?

Comment: it shows nothing now. no friends on the template.

Comment: No, `user` is the user that you got from the database. However, I can see that you are getting it based on request.user - you should just pass in the URL parameter ID, otherwise the profile will also just show the logged-in users'.

Comment: okay. I used id that I am getting from the parameters. it shows nothing now.

Comment: @djangodeveloper I've updated my answer, the Q expression went to `AddToNetwork` but not back to the related users again. It should work now, I've tested it locally.

Comment: okay. I have applied the updated code. it still shows nothing. do I need to use User or get_user_model()? because both are the same.

Comment: They are the same as long as you have registered your `User` model in settings as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` - double check that you have `AddToNetwork` objects that are connected to the expected user objects

Comment: oh. it shows the correct friends n my print statement. I think I need to change it in my templates.

Comment: How should I display them now? I am totally confused now.

Comment: If it appears in your print statement, just make sure that variable is passed to your context and rendered in the template

Comment: so what I was doing, was trying to display the friends' list on templates using AddToNetwork attributes. so got it worked now after changing it to User attributes.

Comment: I think the same concept is going to be implemented for the purpose of adding different users to a team. right?

Comment: so can you please explain a bit what is happening? I just need to understand the concept. I mean how this query is happening to display the friends?